# How to list data in one datastore with geoserver rest interfaces?

Tags: rest, geoserver

I have tried to use "rest/layers.json" to get all data,but only got the services have been published.
I thought it might be 
"rest/workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{datastoreName}/featuretypes.json" ,bu i always get the emty object. 
 it should look like:"rest/workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{datastoreName}/data.json.
so,how to get the data list with a datastore exactly.

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer REST services are only managing configuration, there is not data access. If you want to get data, use WFS, it's really simple, e.g.:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&outputformat=application/json

Comment: Thanks,but maybe i haven't  express myself clear enough .I don't want to get the data,i just want to get the list of table in the datastore  haven't been published to layers.  \n  I have got the answer from the offical doc: using "rest/workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{datastoreName}/featuretypes.json",with the parameters list=available.